# Docker voume does not detect file changes made by a Node.js script on host

Tags: node.js, docker

I have two Node.js scripts, one called `appender.js` that appends lines to a file called `log` (every 500ms), and another script named `watcher.js` that watches changes made to `log`.

```js
// appender.js
const { createWriteStream } = require("fs")

const stream = createWriteStream("log")

setInterval(
    () => stream.write("Hello\n"), 
    500
)
```

```js
// watcher.js
const fs = require('fs')

fs.watch("log", console.log)
```

The changes made by `appender.js` are detected by `watcher.js` when I run both scripts on the host machine using `node appender.js` in one terminal and `node watcher.js` in another.

But things are different when I run `appender.js` on the host machine and `watcher.js` in a docker container.

In this setup, I have a Dockerfile to build the watcher.
The image is built using `docker build -t watcher:latest .`.

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /usr/watcher

COPY watcher.js watcher.js

CMD [ "node", "watcher.js" ]
```

Once the docker image is built, I run `node appender.js` in one terminal and `docker run --rm -it --name watcher -v $(pwd)/log:/usr/watcher/log watcher:latest` in another terminal.
But in this setup, changes are detected only when the appender starts and ends, but not when lines are appended every 500ms.

In the other hand, when I run both scripts in separated docker containers that shares the same volume, then everything works.

The dockerfile for the appender is:

```js
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /usr/appender

COPY appender.js appender.js

CMD [ "node", "appender.js" ]
```

And I build the image with `docker build -t appender:latest -f Dockerfile.appender .`.
Once built, I run `docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd)/log:/usr/appender/log --name appender appender:latest`.

I've also tested the scenario where the appender runs in a docker container and the watcher in the host.

In this scenario, I run `node watcher.js` for the watcher and `docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd)/log:/usr/appender/log --name appender appender:latest`.
In this setup the watcher is detecting the changes correctly.

So, the only case that is not working as expected is when the watcher is in a container and the appender in the host.

Why the watcher, when it is in a docker container, cannot detect changes made by the appender that is running on the host?

Also, I am on macOS Ventura 13.3.1 (M1).
My docker version is `Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be experiencing an issue due to Macs running amd64 containers under emulation. See here https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/known-issues/ on the 'For Mac with Apple silicon' tab:

> However, attempts to run Intel-based containers on Apple silicon
> machines under emulation can crash as qemu sometimes fails to run the
> container. In addition, filesystem change notification APIs (inotify)
> do not work under qemu emulation. Even when the containers do run
> correctly under emulation, they will be slower and use more memory
> than the native equivalent.

inotify is the mechanism used to send file system update events.

A way to fix it could be to have your watcher use polling to check for updates. Try setting the environment variable `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING` to `1` for the watcher, when it runs in a container.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I've tried to run my container with `docker run --rm -it -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=1 -v $(pwd)/log:/usr/watcher/log --name watcher watcher:latest` but the behavior is the same. Also, I've inspected my image and it seem to be a arm image as `docker image inspect cdae858c43d6 --format '{{ .Os }}/{{ .Architecture }}'` returned `linux/arm64`. Also, running `docker run --rm -it --name watcher watcher:latest lscpu` returns `Architecture:            aarch64`. So, I'm think that everything runs without qemu. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, you're right. That sounds like it's not running in the emulator. Then it must be something else.